# What controls "loading" feedback in MVP?

Tags: mvp

I see two basic ways to implement "loading" feedback (e.g. swirly loading icon):

In the presenter:

```
void displayData()
{
    display.startShowingLoadingIcon();
    startLoadingData();
}

void onDataLoaded()
{
    display.stopShowingLoadingIconAndDisplayData(data);
}
```

In the display:

```
void showData()
{
    startShowingLoadingIcon();
    presenter.getData(callback);
}

Callback callback(data)
{
    stopShowingLoadingIconAndDisplayData(data);
}
```

I like the second solution because it seems like loading feedback is clearly a user interface decision.  I don't want my presenter to have to know about any kind of user interaction.  Also, the first solution allows the display some flexibility for the case that the user cancels a request, something else comes up, etc.  On the other hand, the first solution is simpler to implement, and doesn't require the display to know about the presenter.

What do you do?

Answer (score 2):

I think it belongs in the view because:

1: The reason you'd take things out of the view is so you can more easily test it. A simple start/ stop showing loading doesn't seem like a lot of logic worth writing tests for.

2: This feature is so specific to the view, that it feels the presenter shouldn't even have to know about it.

3: Since the view is responsible for knowing how to render itself, it makes sense that it should know how to display a loading icon when needed.